# Doing something wrong with if/else statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm learning the basics of javascript, and i've created some javascript which for some reason doesn't work. I'm probably doing something stupid, but i can't figure out what i am doing wrong. I think it has something to do with the variable "bkosten" but i can't figure out what. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
  <title>JavaScript Lab 01</title>


</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var klantnaam = prompt("Voer je eigen naam in");
    var aantal = parseInt(prompt("Aantal boeken te bestellen?"));
    var woonplaats = prompt("Voer je woonplaats in");
    var minpost = "1000AA";
    var maxpost = "2000BB";
    var postcode = prompt("Voer je postcode in");
    var result1 = postcode.localeCompare(minpost);
    var result2 = postcode.localeCompare(maxpost);
    var titel = "JavaScripts";
    var prijs = 29.90;
    var bedrag = prijs * aantal;
    var btw = 0.06 * bedrag;
    var bezorgkosten = 15;
    var totaalprijsbezorgkosten = bedrag + btw + bezorgkosten;
    var totaalprijsgratisbezorgd = bedrag + btw;

    if (result1 === 1 && result2 === -1) {
      bkosten = false;
    } else {
      bkosten = true;
    }

     if (bkosten === false && woonplaats = "Amsterdam") {
      document.writeln("Bedankt voor je bestelling " + klantnaam + "!<br />");
      document.writeln("Woonplaats " + woonplaats) + "<br />";
      document.writeln("Boektitel is: " + titel + "<br />");
      document.writeln("Aantal te bestellen: " + aantal + "<br />");
      document.writeln("Prijs per boek is " + prijs.toFixed(2) + " (excl. btw <br />");
      document.writeln("De prijs komt neer op " + bedrag.toFixed(2) + " euro                 <br />");
      document.writeln("De BTW bedraagt" + btw.toFixed(2) + " euro <br />");
      document.writeln("Je hebt geen bezorgkosten! <br />");
      document.writeln("De totaalprijs komt neer op " + totaalprijsgratisbezorgd + " euro<br />");
    } else {
      document.writeln("Bedankt voor je bestelling " + klantnaam + "!<br />");
      document.writeln("Woonplaats " + woonplaats) + "<br />";
      document.writeln("Boektitel is: " + titel + "<br />");
      document.writeln("Aantal te bestellen: " + aantal + "<br />");
      document.writeln("Prijs per boek is " + prijs.toFixed(2) + " (excl. btw) <br />");
      document.writeln("De prijs komt neer op " + bedrag.toFixed(2) + " euro <br />");
      document.writeln("De BTW bedraagt" + btw.toFixed(2) + " euro <br />");
      document.writenl("De bezorgkosten bedragen" + bezorkosten + "<br />");
      document.writeln("De totaalprijs komt neer op " + totaalprijsbezorgkosten + " euro<br />");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I may have messed up some of the code trying to paste it in this question, but it works when i don't use the bkosten variable.

Comment: `bkosten === false` should be `!bkosten`; it is bad form and duplicate logic to compare boolean variables like this.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - the two statements, in the context of the code, are identical

Comment: I might be missing something, but where is "bkosten" defined? I don't see a variable declaration.

Comment: PS: When trying to post examples on SO, try to write [simple examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that isolate the issue you have. Remove anything not related. Sometimes, just doing that will help you find the bug too.

Comment: As Jacque said: It can be very difficult to help unless you simplify the question and only show the code essential to the issue:

That being said, you might want to have a look at the following line:
If( ..... && woonplaats = "Amsterdam"). Remember to use === for regular string comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Simply a typo most likely:

`woonplaats = "Amsterdam"` should be `woonplaats === "Amsterdam"`

and the following is more verbose than it needs to be and the scope of `bkosten` is most likely wrong. But since I do not know what `bkosten` means I can't tell if it should be global or not so ...

```
if (result1 === 1 && result2 === -1) {
  bkosten = false;
}
else {
  bkosten = true;
}
```

so the correct code should look like

```
var bkosten = (result === 1 && result2 === -1);
if (!bkosten && woonplaats === "Amsterdam") {
   // logic goes here
}
```

Comment: Thans you guys for your help. Next time i will narrow the code down to the part i think has the problem. @Jarrod: it was that what you said. Once i changed it, it worked like a charm! Thank you!